# Implementing a file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

How would I go about implementing my own file descriptor?
Say if I have a kernel module controlling some hardware and I want to expose the ability to communicate with this hardware to the userspace via read() and write(). Don't want to use IOCTL or netlink or other userspace-kernelspace methods. Would I need to recompile the kernel or can I do it just by writing a kernel module.

I understand that creating the file descriptor will require a mechanism for userspace to tell the kernelspace to create an entry in the task's files struct (ie a function equivalent to open(), eventfd() timerfd(), socket()). That I can implement via IOCTL (so that I wont have to recompile the kernel), but how do I hack into read() and write() - I have patched them using LD_PRELOAD before, is that the only way? Don't want to recompile the kernel!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all of your questions. Nonetheless:

- you can definitely have this as a kernel module;
- you probably want to create a character device (second part of your question);
- for the char device you can implement the system calls you need; if you only want to have `read` and `write` - no problem;

Look at the chapter three (and others) of this [book](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Answer (score 0):

konrad.kruczynski is right!

use a character device as the userspace mechanism to communicate with your hardware, and create a device in /dev filesystem such as /dev/hardware_type_A.

then compile && load your module in the kernel, then if all your code is good, then the kernel will create a character device in /dev/ with name /dev/hardware_type_A.

then you can use read, write, open, close calls just like you use with the other devices or the files to control your hardware.

IF you really say that you dont want to control it over ioctl, then you must need a new protocol that sends data using write and your driver unpacks that data and controls the hardware on behalf of your program in user.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @konrad.kruczynski & John. Currently character device/ioctl is the way I have implemented the communication between userspace and kernelspace. I pass pointers to data structures to KS using ioctl and the kernel side module extracts the data from that struct. But the thing is I need an entity in userspace on which i can use select(). I need a way to signal US when an event happens on the kernel side. I know there are other ways to send signals to US but is there some way that US can wait using select()? can I use select() with character device?

Comment: thats really possible by the kernel using the poll apis. see linux/poll.h, when a request comes from the userspace add it to the waitqueue and wake it up if you have data from the driver. search for the wake_up_interruptible in the drivers/char/ folder in kernel sources. this eventually improves your driver as well by reducing the cpu usages in waiting...